# Do not apply lambda function to missing values

Tags: python, pandas, apply

I have a dataframe with the patient's diagnosis in a column and using pandas I want to dichotomize the diagnosis ==> ISM, non ISM. I tried this

```
df["initial_diagnosis"] = df["initial_diagnosis"].apply(lambda x: x if x=="ISM" else "non ISM")
```

But it is assigning "non ISM" also to missing values. Is there a way to do the same and keep the missing values as they are?

The column that I'm trying to code looks like this:

```
initial_diagnosis    I
ISM 
ISM
WDSM
NaN
ISM
SSM
CM
ASM
ISM
```

Comment: It would really help if you could share a snippet of your data (i.e. `df['initia_diagnosis`]) .

Comment: Why not just change the apply function to ignore elements which are null?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it should work.
Probably missing values are empty strings or just None, I can only guess

```
missing_values = {...} # Set of values you want to keep
df["initial_diagnosis"] = df["initial_diagnosis"].apply(lambda x: x if x=="ISM" or x in missing_values else "non ISM")
```

**Edit**:

```
import pandas as pd
from numpy import nan

data = pd.read_csv("test.csv")
print(data['initial_diagnosis']) 

#0    ISM
#1     ISM
#2    WDSM
#3     NaN
#4     ISM
#5     SSM
#6      CM
#7     ASM
#8     ISM 
#Name: initial_diagnosis, dtype: object

missing_values = {nan}
data["initial_diagnosis"] = data["initial_diagnosis"].apply(lambda x: x if x =="ISM" or x in missing_values else "non ISM")
print(data['initial_diagnosis'])

#0    non ISM
#1        ISM
#2    non ISM
#3        NaN
#4        ISM
#5    non ISM
#6    non ISM
#7    non ISM
#8        ISM
```